# find availabe internal memory in runtime from code

Tags: java, android, sqlite, memory-management

i must find the available internal memory in runtime from code because when i lower internal phone memory to less than 100K, sqlite operations throw SQLiteDiskIOException on each db operation, due to insufficient disk space

any ideas?

clahav

Comment: Hmmm... Don't use so much memory then.

Answer (score 3):

In such a case, using an embedded DB seems overkill, as you have a low amount of RAM and, as a consequence, a weak environment. I would instead prefer prevalent layer like

- [Space4J](http://www.space4j.org/)
- [Prevayler](http://www.prevayler.org/)

You'll loose some features over JDBC (transaction, SQL), but your memory consumption can be really lowered.

Comment: experts. from your comments i discovered that i did not mention that this issue occurs in an android app. i can wrap each sqlite operation and catch the ioexception but i rather have a reusable method that checks for the available internal phone memory left. this is a disk storage issue and not a memory exception thrown by the jvm

Comment: Please add that to your question, then.

Comment: this is how to do itFile path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
return Formatter.formatFileSize(this, availableBlocks * blockSize);

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` gives you an estimate of the amount of free memory.  However, it is not a particularly useful measure, since there is a good chance that you can allocate more memory than the reported value.  When you try to allocate more memory than is currently free, the JVM will automatically run the GC in an attempt to reclaim enough space for your allocation, and this will usually succeed.

You *can* request the GC to run "right now" by calling `System.gc()`, but this is generally a **bad idea** from a performance perspective.  The GC is most efficient (in terms of time spent per byte reclaimed) if you just let the JVM run the GC when it needs to.  The only case where it can be worthwhile to run the GC is if you know that you have CPU cycles to spare at a particular point and you want to mitigate GC pauses.

---

In your particular case, I'm not sure what advantage there is in knowing how much free memory there is.  Why don't you just try the sqlite operations and catch / deal with the exceptions?  Or increase the heap size?  Or track down what is leaking memory or using it inefficiently?

Answer (score 0):

```
Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.freeMemory()
```

calling System.gc() may increasing the available free memory

Comment: In fact, both operations **may** trigger a garbage collection operation,, but it depends upon the GC implementation, which can as well perform GC operation as not.